# django url not matching right url with reverse match error

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I'm getting very unusual error in my django project because django reads the wrong url not stated in the href tag being clicked. The page to be navigated to is just a page with a simple url pattern whilst the page it's navigating to requires two arguments for reverse matching which are expectedly not supplied and this leads to the error:

> Reverse for 'search-friend-detail' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['chat/search\-friend\-detail/(?P[^/]+)/(?P[^/]+)/$']

urls.py:

```
 urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('users.urls')),
    path('posts/home.html', p_views.PostsListView.as_view(), name='posts-home'),
    path('friends/search.html', f_views.search, name='friends-search'),
    path('friends/add-friend/', f_views.SearchDetail, name='friends-search-detail'),
    path('friends/accept-requests/', f_views.AcceptRequests, name='accept-requests'),
    path('friends/accept-requests-detail/', f_views.AcceptRequestsDetail, name='accept-requests-detail'),
    path('chat/chatt.html', pc_views.SearchChat, name='chat-search'),
    path('chat/search-friend-detail/<str:username>/<str:usernamee>/', pc_views.SearchChatDetail, name='search-friend-detail'),
]
```

the "chat-search" is the actual url i wish to navigate to in base.html file through this link:

```
<a href="{% url 'chat-search' %}"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
```

but instead miraculously navigating to the last url i.e 'search-friend-search'.
although the link is in my chatt.html file at:

```
<a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'search-friend-detail' results.Accepter.username results.Added.username %}">{{ results.Added.username }}</a>
```

edit: for clarity,the full chatt.html file;

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            b{% extends "posts/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %} 
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-5 mx-auto">
<form method="POST" class="form-signin">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-label-group">
            {{ form|crispy}}
            </div>
            
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase" type="submit">Search</button> 
            </form>
            </div>
            {% if results.Accepter == request.user %}
            <article class="media content-section">
            <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ results.Added.profile.image.url }}">
            <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'search-friend-detail' results.Accepter.username results.Added.username %}">{{ results.Added.username }}</a>
            <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
            {% else %}
            <article class="media content-section">
            <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ results.Accepter.profile.image.url }}">
            <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'search-friend-detail' results.Accepter.username results.Added.username %}">{{ results.Accepter.username }}</a>
            <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
            {% endif %}
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

my views.py:

```
def SearchChat(request):
    result=None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form= ChatFriend(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data.get('chatsearch')
            userr = User.objects.get(username=name)
            if FriendList.objects.filter(Accepter=request.user,Added=userr).exists():
                result = FriendList.objects.get(Accepter=request.user,Added=userr)
            else:
                result = FriendList.objects.get(Accepter=userr,Added=request.user)
    else:
        form= ChatFriend()
    context={
           'results': result,
           'form':form,
            }
    return render(request, 'chat/chatt.html', context)

def SearchChatDetail(request, username, usernamee):
    Acceptor= User.objects.get(username=username)
    Addid= User.objects.get(username=username)
    friend= FriendList.objects.get(Accepter=Acceptor,Added=Addid)
    msgs= Chat.objects.filter(messengers=friend)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form= message(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            redirect('search-friend-detail',friend.Accepter.username,friend.Added.username)
    else:
        form= message(instance=request.user)
            
    context={
        'friend':friend,
        'msgs':msgs,
        'form':form,
        }
    return render(request, 'chat/search-friend-detail.html', context)
```

edit: i forgot to mention that the first time i ran the code it worked,just slept for few hours to come back to the next task then starts generating an error without touching the code at all.

Comment: Because `results` is not initialized in GET response. Thus `results.Accepter.username`, `results.Added.username` are both `none` and url reversion mechanism cannot build that url.

Comment: tried initializing result in he GET response but since i will definitely have to pass context or result in any of the if statements i get an unbound value error cause the variable was passed before initialization

Comment: Your `chatt.html` template is apparently trying to display links to search result details when the search form is still blank, before you have any search results. It would help if you edit your post to show your `chatt.html` template.

Comment: `none` does not seem have `Accepter.username` which is needed to build the URL.

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem after reading evergreen's reply properly,my bad i was comparing this view to another view i wrote that worked effectively but just remembered i used ajax requests to execute the views code instead of loading a new template has done in this problem, all i did was add a conditional statement to show only the search form when the searchh form is empty.
Answered this cause i know there are others who will face this problem later on.